# Can you please share the link to book appointment at italian consulate in san francisco

Tags: schengen, italy

I need to book appointment for visa stamping at the Italian consulate in San Francisco. Can you share the link to schedule appointment

Comment: Have you triedv googling Italian Consulate San Francisco?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is too localized to be of much use to future visitors.

Answer (score 2):

The English version of the Italian consulate in San Francisco is [here](http://www.conssanfrancisco.esteri.it/consolato_sanfrancisco/en/). I'm assuming English is preferred to Italian as you're post was in English. There is an icon by the search box to change language if you'd like, however.

Visa information is [here](http://www.conssanfrancisco.esteri.it/consolato_sanfrancisco/en/i_servizi/per_i_cittadini/visas.html)

The second section of that page contains a link to the site you would use to book your appointment, [here](https://prenotaonline.esteri.it/Login.aspx?cidsede=100012&returnUrl=//)

Comment: @pnuts The question explicitly calls for a link. I'm not sure how one is supposed to answer such a question in a way that doesn't depend on the link still working, though I'll note that Sean has provided several links, so a future reader can still find their way to the appropriate page even if the appointment booking site changes.